# Thousands point and decimal comma HighCharts

Tags: highcharts, decimal, point, separator

I am trying to invert the punctuation marks on all charts in High Chats, leave them as default

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.setOptions({
lang: {
thousandsSep: '.',
decimalPoint: ','
}
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
type: 'column'
},

title: {
text: 'Short weekdays option'
},

tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
  return this.y.toString().replace('.', '?');
}
},
</script>
```

The idea is to find a script that affects all charts, regardless of whether the column is floating or integer data.

Best

Comment: It seems that the part of the code which you shared actually does it. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/he1rfo5n/ Could you explain more precisely where the problem is? Or share a demo of the issue where it doesn't work as expected?